# Why is MATLAB failing to successfully read in binary files?

Tags: matlab, file-io

Matlab is failing to read in the specified number of elements from a file.  I have a simple program that needs to read in two files, perform a linear operation on the data and write a combined result to a third file.

My questions are: 1) Why does Matlab fail to read the specified number of elements and 2) is there a workaround for this? *Any* of your thoughts will be helpful.

Some details on the input files:

- they are large (~18GB)
- they are both the same size (exactly)

Details on the procedure (2-4 are conditioned on an `feof` check of both files:

1. Open the input and output files for reading and writing (resp.)
2. Read in `N` floats (N*4 bytes) from each of the input files
3. Perform an operation on the data (say 0.5*(datin1+datin2))
4. Write the result to the output file.

Granted, this is all very simple and in most cases in the past this has worked well.  Unfortunately, at some point in the cycle, MATLAB doesn't get all `N` floats from one of the files and gives a matrix dimension error on step 3.

CODE SNIP:

```
N = 2048;
fidin1 = fopen('file1.dat','r','l');
fidin2 = fopen('file2.dat','r','l');
fidout = fopen('outfile.dat','w','l');

%# I could do some assertions on the file sizes,
%# but I know they are the same size (w/o question).

while(~feof(fidin1) && ~feof(fidin2))
    datin1 = fread(fidin1,N,'float=>single',0,'l');
    datin2 = fread(fidin2,N,'float=>single',0,'l');

    %# the following line produces an error after 100 
    %# or more iterations in to the procedure
    datout = 0.5*(datin1+datin2);
    fwrite(fidout,datout,'float',0,'l');
end
```

**UPDATE 1**
The error message I'm receiving is:

```
???Error using ==> plus
Matrix dimension must agree.
```

**UPDATE 2**
I followed a suggestion and included `ferror`checks after each read and *magically* the problem went away.  **So now a modification to my questions**: What could be the root of the problem here?  Is this simply a timing issue or bug?

Here is a snip of the updated code (showing only a portion of the code).  I'm sure there are better ways to do this.  Regardless, the addition of these checks allowed Matlab to complete all the reads from each of the files successfully.

```
    [datin1 count1]= fread(fidin1,N,'float=>single',0,'l');
    [msg errn1]=ferror(fidin1);
    if errn1
        pos1 = ftell(fidin1);
        error('Error at Position %d in file.  %d bytes were read.',...
            pos1,count1);
    end

    [datin2 count2]= fread(fidin2,N,'float=>single',0,'l');
    [msg errn2]=ferror(fidin2);
    if errn2
        pos2 = ftell(fidin2);
        error('Error at Position %d in file.  %d bytes were read.',...
            pos2,count2);
    end

    %# the following line produces an error after 100 
    %# or more iterations in to the procedure
    datout = 0.5*(datin1+datin2);
    fwrite(fidout,datout,'float',0,'l');
```

Comment: Can you include the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Are both files on an internal hard disc? and what OS are you on? 32 or 64bit matlab?

Comment: @ Andrew, `Error using ==> plus ... Matrix dimensions must agree`.

Comment: @Sanjay, they are on the same internal disc, OS => XP, with 64b Matlab. I thought this might have something to do with the file size/ filesystem limitations (I'm admittedly a bit Windows ignorant here), but Matlab had no trouble writing the files.  The input files were written by Matlab.

Comment: Check ferror() after each fread(). And how about [A, count] = fread(...) and tell us how many elements? I'm guessing there was some file error but the Matlab docs don't say if A is padded to size N after a file error.

Comment: @Erik, good point.  I'm running that ATM.

Comment: @Erik, I'm assuming that what I was witnessing was a timing issue of some sort.  I inserted the `ferror()` checks as well as some conditional code that called `ftell()` to get the current position in the file where the error took place.  The insertion of these extra calls resulted in Matlab successfully reading every time. If I remove the checks, the error occurs. What do you think?

Comment: Where are the errors occurring?  How many bytes have you read in before it pukes on you?  Is the location consistent or does it change?

Comment: @John, it changes. without the added checks, it will make it through 5GB one run and get all the way to 17GB on another (I really like it when it gets nice and close before dying :) ).

The current workaround of including some added checks is allowing it to do it's job for now.  Once I am finished with my current deliverable for the day, I will run some scripts aimed at diagnosing the issue and provide some numbers on where it's failing.

Comment: You didn't state your platform? Win7, 64 bit, Matlab release, etc?

Comment: @Erik, Matlab R2011a, 32-bit, running on WinXP 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you specifically looked at the datin1 and datin2 variables at the time the error occurs?  Try going to 'Debug-->Stop if Errors/Warnings...' then select 'Always stop if error (dstop if error)'.  Run your program and then once it crashes, look at datin1 and datin2.  Hopefully that will explain why adding them together is now working.

Comment: That's new to me.  Thanks for pointing out this approach.  As it turns out, the error is intermittent with large files.  Maybe this approach will help me figure out why.

My current solution has been to write out file-segments which are much smaller.  Since I have made this change, no errors have occurred, which leads me to believe this is a file-size problem.